# How can i read each value from xml below?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read each xml value below but  it reads only first four values.

XmlFile:

```
<session
    beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30"
    halSerialNumber="08J-0735"
    testMode="Remote"
    userName="Myname">
    <appliance overallResult="Passed" partNumber="AN-02-203" serialNumber="3">
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                arcDetect="0"
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="HiPot 50Hz"
                numTests="1"
                startConditions="StartKey"
                targetOutputKilovolts="1.50"
                testVoltageOutput="Back"
                timeHoldSeconds="2.0"
                timeRampDownSeconds="0.0"
                timeRampUpSeconds="0.0"
                type="HiPot50"
                upperLimitMilliamps="20.00"
            />
            <test_result
                appliedOutputKilovolts="1.50"
                leakageMilliamps="0.57"
                testDurationSeconds="2.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2018-05-11T10:39:29"
            />
        </test_set>
        <test_set testState="Passed">
            <test
                lowerLimitMilliamps="0.00"
                name="Power Leakage"
                numTests="1"
                powerFactorLowerLimit="0.000"
                powerFactorUpperLimit="1.000"
                powerLowerLimitKVA="3.00"
                powerUpperLimitKVA="4.00"
                reversePolarity="0"
                timeHoldSeconds="3.0"
                type="PowerLeakage"
                upperLimitMilliamps="20.00"
            />
            <test_result
                leakageMilliamps="0.05"
                powerAV="3.437"
                powerFactor="1.000"
                testDurationSeconds="3.00"
                testState="Passed"
                timeOfTest="2018-05-11T10:39:33"
            />
        </test_set>
    </appliance>
</session>
```

I'm trying to create a table with xml values

```
public System.Data.DataTable CreateDataTableFromXml(string XmlFile)
        {

            System.Data.DataTable Dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(XmlFile);
                Dt.Load(ds.CreateDataReader());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return Dt;
        }
```

and then to export this table to excel the problem is that i 'm taking only first four values till username.
I thing that something is wrong with my xml file, is there any way to change that?

Comment: First step: Remove the exception-eating empty `catch` clause to see what's acutally going on.

Comment: You want one table? How does the hierarchy need to be collapsed then?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading into a DataSet and then returning only one (top level) DataTable. Here is the sample with your XML:

```
void Main()
{
        ShowTablesFromXml(@"d:\temp\myxml.xml");
}

public void ShowTablesFromXml(string XmlFile)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(XmlFile);
        foreach (DataTable t in ds.Tables)
        {
            ShowData(t);
        }

}

public void ShowData(DataTable t)
{
    Form f = new Form();
    f.Controls.Add(new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=t });
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it show 3 tables separately how can i combine them in one?

Comment: Please help how can i combine seperated  rows in datatable into one?

Comment: @Dimitris, if I were you, I would instead load this data using XElement. I can send a sample later if I have time.

Comment: Adding as another answer since it is long.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml2CSharp.com's converter got the class codes and run in LinqPad (.Dump() is built-in to LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Session));
    var sess = serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(@"d:\temp\myxml.xml"));
    sess.Dump();
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "arcDetect")]
    public string ArcDetect { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lowerLimitMilliamps")]
    public string LowerLimitMilliamps { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "numTests")]
    public string NumTests { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "startConditions")]
    public string StartConditions { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "targetOutputKilovolts")]
    public string TargetOutputKilovolts { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testVoltageOutput")]
    public string TestVoltageOutput { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timeHoldSeconds")]
    public string TimeHoldSeconds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timeRampDownSeconds")]
    public string TimeRampDownSeconds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timeRampUpSeconds")]
    public string TimeRampUpSeconds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "upperLimitMilliamps")]
    public string UpperLimitMilliamps { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerFactorLowerLimit")]
    public string PowerFactorLowerLimit { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerFactorUpperLimit")]
    public string PowerFactorUpperLimit { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerLowerLimitKVA")]
    public string PowerLowerLimitKVA { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerUpperLimitKVA")]
    public string PowerUpperLimitKVA { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "reversePolarity")]
    public string ReversePolarity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test_result")]
public class Test_result
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "appliedOutputKilovolts")]
    public string AppliedOutputKilovolts { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "leakageMilliamps")]
    public string LeakageMilliamps { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testDurationSeconds")]
    public string TestDurationSeconds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testState")]
    public string TestState { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timeOfTest")]
    public string TimeOfTest { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerAV")]
    public string PowerAV { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "powerFactor")]
    public string PowerFactor { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test_set")]
public class Test_set
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "test")]
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "test_result")]
    public Test_result Test_result { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testState")]
    public string TestState { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "appliance")]
public class Appliance
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "test_set")]
    public List<Test_set> Test_set { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "overallResult")]
    public string OverallResult { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "partNumber")]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "serialNumber")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "session")]
public class Session
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "appliance")]
    public Appliance Appliance { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "beginTime")]
    public string BeginTime { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "halSerialNumber")]
    public string HalSerialNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "testMode")]
    public string TestMode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code flattens your XML document into a single datatable with all attributes as columns.

I have added comments in the code to explain what it is doing. It relies mostly on the LINQ to XML features: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// the new DataTable
var tbl = new DataTable();

// load XML file
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\tmp\sess-test.xml");

// get the leaf elements and their common ancestor
var q = from elements in doc.Descendants()
        where elements.Descendants().Count() == 0
        group elements by  elements.Parent into cluster
        from item in cluster
        from Attributes in item.Attributes()
        select new 
            {  cluster.Key, // common ancestor
               Attributes,  // elements attributes
               AncestorAttributes = cluster.Key.AncestorsAndSelf().Attributes()  // attributes in Ancestors of the common element

            };

// create a column for each Ancestor attribute
foreach(var attr in q.GroupBy( b=> b.Key).SelectMany(b => b.First().AncestorAttributes)) 
{
   if (tbl.Columns[attr.Name.LocalName] == null) {
          tbl.Columns.Add(attr.Name.LocalName);
    }
}

// create a column for each element attribute
foreach(var grp in q)
{
    if (tbl.Columns[grp.Attributes.Name.LocalName] == null) {
          tbl.Columns.Add(grp.Attributes.Name.LocalName);
    }
}

// build datatable
var grps = q.GetEnumerator();
bool next = grps.MoveNext();
// for each group a new row  
var curgrp = grps.Current.Key;
var row = tbl.NewRow();
// add attribute values to this row
while(next)
{
    if (curgrp != grps.Current.Key) {
        // new group, so new row
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        row = tbl.NewRow();
        curgrp = grps.Current.Key;
    }
    // attribute gets stored
    row[grps.Current.Attributes.Name.LocalName] = grps.Current.Attributes.Value ;
    // all attributes from the ancestors get stored
    foreach(var attr in grps.Current.AncestorAttributes)
    {
        row[attr.Name.LocalName] = attr.Value ;
    }
    next = grps.MoveNext();
}
tbl.Rows.Add(row);
```

When this code is run using your example XML this is the output you'll find in the DataTable:

[image]

Notice that the screenshot is cutoff. It has all the attributes as columns.